# Why do I get 1001 error every time I try to login into Naukari.com using my selenium test script?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

[Naukari error img: I am getting This error on naukari page but on doing manually it does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM1xw.png)

I am trying to automate Naukari.com so that it gets updated daily on its own instead of me visiting the website daily to do it. My script is as follows:

```
package naukariUpdate;

import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import naukariLoginPOM.LoginPOM;

public class NaukariUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
        driver.getTitle();
        String mainWindowTitle = driver.getTitle();
        String mainWindowID = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String handleID : s)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(handleID);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            String windowID = driver.getTitle();
            if (!windowID.equals(mainWindowTitle))
            {
                driver.close();
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowID);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[text()='Login'])[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Google']")).click();
        Set<String> window = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println();
        for (String handleID : window) 
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(handleID);
            String windowTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(windowTitle+"\t"+mainWindowTitle);
            if (!windowTitle.equals(mainWindowTitle))
            {
                System.out.println("in IF");
                driver.switchTo().window(handleID);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("out of switching "+driver.getTitle());
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement webElement =     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement));
        LoginPOM POM = new LoginPOM(driver);
        WebElement logIN = POM.getLogIn();
        logIN.sendKeys("Sorry type in your own email ID bro");
        WebElement nextBtn = POM.NextButton();
        nextBtn.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(POM.getPassword()));
        WebElement pswd = POM.getPassword();
        pswd.sendKeys("Sorry type in your own password bro");
        nextBtn.click();
    }
}
```

This is the POM:

```
package naukariLoginPOM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPOM {
    public LoginPOM(WebDriver driver) 
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver , this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='identifierId']")
    private WebElement LogIn;
    public WebElement getLogIn()
    {
        return LogIn;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='password']")
    private WebElement Pswd;
    public WebElement getPassword()
    {
        return Pswd;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//content[.='Next']")
    private WebElement NextBtn;
    public WebElement NextButton()
    {
        return NextBtn;
    }
}
```

I don't get where I made the mistake. Everything seems to run fine, yet I get error 1001 in the end. This does not happen when I carry out the process manually by clicking and typing. How can I resolve it?

Comment: What is `error 1001` all about? At which line? Error stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Error #1001 is an issue with adobe flash player. You will need to redeploy (reinstall) your adobe flash player as it either missing critical libraries or those libraries are corrupted. This is a documented error with Adobe. You can read more about the issue from this link here:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/258374?start=0&tstart=0

Unfortunately, this is not an issue that is related to Selenium.

The solution is to reinstall your adobe flash player. If your permissions on your workstation are not high enough to do this, ask your IT team.

Comment: Pretty helpful analysis and the link was useful.